# libspotify: log out time

Tags: spotify

How long does it usually take between calling **sp_session_logout** and the callback **logged_out** gets called? From my experience, sometimes it's fast, but sometimes it takes few seconds. For example, sometimes search takes longer, browse is ok.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`From my experience, sometimes it's fast, but sometimes it takes few seconds.`

That's your answer. It takes "some time". Logging out does a bunch of stuff like flushing disk caches and so on as well as disconnecting the user from the service.

Comment: So it does depend. I hoped the long delay was due to other reasons.

Comment: Like every operation in a library that relies on communication with an external service, yes, the time to carry the operation out can change.